# Cent OS 7, ImageMagick command not found

Tags: linux, bash, imagemagick

ImageMagick was successfully installed, but command "magick" not found. 
OS: Cent OS 7 x64, ImageMagic -6.7.8.9-15.el7_2.x86_64, what else does he need to use the team?

Comment: What should do the `magick` command ? Maybe reading the docs could help, how to use the `composite`, `convert`, `mogrify`, `identify` and few other commands contained in the ImageMagick...

Comment: ImageMagick 6.7.8.9 uses convert, not magick. To use magick, you need the IM 7.x.x.x. version.

Answer (score 0):

The command `$ rpm -ql [package-name]` will print a "package file list".

```
$ rpm -ql ImageMagick | grep bin

/usr/bin/animate
/usr/bin/compare
/usr/bin/composite
/usr/bin/conjure
/usr/bin/convert
/usr/bin/display
/usr/bin/identify
/usr/bin/import
/usr/bin/mogrify
/usr/bin/montage
/usr/bin/stream
```